# mysqldump not copying all data

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, mysql

I have a MySQL DB that is the backend for my drupal web site, I am going through the drupal upgrade and before I do the upgrade I need to make a copy of the database.

```
mysqladmin create ts_prod_bak -u root --password=XXXXXX && \
  mysqldump -u root --password=XXXXXX ts_prod | mysql -u root --password=XXXXXX -h localhost ts_prod_bak
```

This does create a new DB called ts_prod_bak and fills that DB with data from ts_prod but it isn't copying all of the data.  I see some tables, cache_* that are created in the new DB but have a different size than the source.  Because of this I am not confident in my backup/copy.

How can I make an exact duplicate of my source database and verify that by restoring it to another DB?

Comment: that's to be expected. your new db file has none of the leftover "garbage" that the original one has. essentially you've "defragged" your DB, and that makes all of the file sizes different.

Comment: If I used optomize DB on the source, would it get rid of the garbage?  Or what can I do so the source and backup are equal?

Comment: no idea how good an optimize run is. it may defrag things somewhat, but if it takes thing down to a "fresh out of the box" state, ... no idea. mysqldump does dump EVERYTHING in a database, unless you explicitly tell it not to. you can be pretty sure that what got dumped is what was in the db.

Comment: Have you considered making your database backup using Backup and Migrate Drupal module? https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate